# Using knockout to build table with 1 odd input

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

Sorry the question subject may not be very accurate but I'm not sure what else to label it as.

I'm trying to cleanly create this 2x of this table using knockoutjs
[image: dynamic table]

All the calculations for both the conservative and compare column are the same except that the compare column is using a drop down instead of a static input.

I'm currently using a function that declares all of the observables for both columns and the protection factor is a ko.calculated that updates all the other observables.

I know there has to be a better way to do this since i'm just repeating the same code and declaring variables like aCoverage  and bCoverage

```
function vm() {
  self.tables = ko.observableArray();
  self.tables.push({table: new summaryTable(data)});
}
function summaryTable(data){
  this.aindem = ko.observable();
  this.alevel = ko.observable(data.level);
  this.blevel = ko.observable({id:90,name:"90%"}); //populate dropdown
  this.bindem = ko.observable();
  this.apremium = ko.observable();
  this.bpremium = ko.observable();
  this.afactor = ko.computed(function() {
    this.aindem(1+2);
    this.apremium(3+4);
  });
  this.bfactor = ko.computed(function() {
    this.bindem(1+2);
    this.apremium(3+4);
}
```

There is one external input that will trigger the computed to re-evaluate.
Because there is it's soo much code I just made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0xfowwd/2/)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you need to do. Please, try to explain more clearly the problem.You've takent the time to create a fiddle, do it's a pity not to know what the problem is to hlep you. Which is the repeated code? The `afactor` and `bfactor` make no sense as computed. And the fiddle has so much code that it's impossible to know where to pay attention.

Comment: @JotaBe Really the fiddle does not have much unique code it just that 2 large code blocks are total repeats of each other. I'm just not sure how to build the table in the image and eliminate the need for 2 duplicate code blocks. The 2 columns left of the labels column run the exact same calculations but one of the inputs needs to be a dropdown. All the HTML section is just table template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a better approach would be to use a primary object instance and then subsequent compare object instances (more than one comparison) and binding to these instances using foreach. I have updated your fiddle to demo this

http://jsfiddle.net/ffd4492e/2/

each column corresponds to an instance of the summary object, and I added a flag to indicate if it is comparison or primary object.

```
 self.primaryFlag = ko.observable(primaryFlag);
    if(!primaryFlag)
        self.head="Compare";
```

then in the binding markup

```
<td data-bind="visible:primaryFlag, text:score"></td>
<td><select data-bind="visible:!primaryFlag(),options:allLevels, optionsText:'name', value:selLevel"></select></td>
```

the dropdown would only show if it is comparison instance ...

I have removed the duplicate fields as well. I hope this sheds some light in your problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Your solution does eliminate the extra code block. I had thought about breaking the table in order to go to an answer like this. I was wondering if there is any way to achieve the same result without breaking the table (tacking on the columns outside of the main table object)

Comment: you could also make the comparison objects child objects of the primary instance ...  then you can keep the table intact but you will need to bind each row to of the table to generate the comparison value .,.. http://jsfiddle.net/j0xfowwd/3/  ...  <td>Protection Factor</td>
              <td data-bind="text:sProtectionFactor"></td>
                <!-- ko foreach: comparisons -->
                  <td data-bind="text:sProtectionFactor"></td>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tr>

Comment: This leads me to believe that there is no way to keep from breaking the table without having the duplicate code. I feel my subject line might have made some confusion. I'm more interested going toward the direction of your posted answer as this is exactly the direction I want to go. Just wondering if it is possible without breaking the table. Even using custom bind elements or anything. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me with this issue.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer. I ended up not using a table and instead just used CSS fluxbox column styling. The use of the visible option on the passed flag was helpful in implementing that. Thank you

Comment: Ah! that sounds very neat.

Answer (score 0):

Your demo doesn't actually do anything when values are changed. It's hard to tell what you want it to do. An example with just a few variables would be less difficult to understand.

You have chosen to make many observables and a couple of computeds, and the computeds set a bunch of the observables. That is not a straightforward approach. Your observables should hold the independent values, and values that are calculated based on independent values should be computeds.

Let's look at just two of your variables:

```
self.sCoveragePA((self.score / 100 * data.refBaseValue * ffactor).toFixed(2) );
self.cCoveragePA((self.selLevel().id / 100 * data.refBaseValue * ffactor).toFixed(2));
```

They differ in just one of their inputs. If you wanted to have just one `coveragePA` variable that could be used in both places, make it a computed that is dependent on another member which is a computed. In one case, the computed would just return `self.score`; in the other case, `self.selLevel().id`.

```
self.coveragePA = ko.computed(function () {
  return (self.controlVar() / 100 * data.refBaseValue * ffactor).toFixed(2);
});
```